# "Please fill out this field" after adding

Tags: javascript, html

After adding the task, appears the message "Please fill in this field".
I use the function setCustomValidity() and default verification form.

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const text = document.querySelector(".text");
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const list = document.querySelector(".list");

const add = function() {
  let valueText = text.value;
  
  if (valueText === "") {
    text.setCustomValidity("Error");
    return false;
  } else {
    text.setCustomValidity("");
  }
  
  const elementItem = document.createElement("li");
  elementItem.setAttribute("class", "item");
  list.appendChild(elementItem);
  elementItem.textContent = valueText;
  
  text.value = "";
}

button.addEventListener("click", add.bind(this));
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <input type="text" class="text" required>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Hey Kabum. Could you please explain what the actual problem or error is you are facing?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what libraries/techniques you're using for displaying tooltips?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `required` attribute applied on `input` field, as you are already managing this in `js` code.

`<input type="text" class="text" required>` should be `<input type="text" class="text">`.